# How to get a range of elements in an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, range, element

I need to calculate the sum of negative elements of an array located between the largest and the smallest elements. Here's the code I've got so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int arrSize = 0;
        cout << "Enter an array size" << endl;
        cin >> arrSize;
    if (arrSize <= 0) {
        cerr << "Entered number is negative or 0" << endl;
        return 0;
    }                               // check if arrSize is 0 or negative, print error if so
    
    double* arr = new double [arrSize];            //declare array

    for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        cout << "Enter array element " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> arr[i];
    }                                              // get elements of array
    
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arrSize; i++) {
        if (max < arr[i])
            max = arr[i];
    }                                              //find max value of array

    int min = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arrSize; i++) {
        if (min > arr[i])
            min = arr[i];
    }                                              //find min value of array
```

How would I go about finding the positions of max and min elements and getting the range in between them?

Comment: You don't need two loops to calculate min and max, you can do it in the same loop.

Comment: You can calculate the `min` and `max` in the same loop you are entering values from the User.

Comment: As for the problem, perhaps add two more variables: `max_index` and `min_index`, which are assigned the value of `i` when you also assign `max` and `min`?

Comment: Actually @ThomasMatthews is correct. You only one single loop, and unless you want to display more than the min and max values and their indexes, you don't even need an array.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element

Comment: `double* arr = new double [arrSize];` Don't do that. Use `std::vector`.